# Auto resize the textbox so that scroll bars are not needed (or detect actual number of lines after wrapping occurs)

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I need to resize my form based on the textbox contents. Currently, I can't reliabley detect the actual number of lines in the textbox.text. All I can do is count the occurrence of the `\n` character, but that does not take into account automatic word wrapping.

And the characters do not have a fixed width, so I can't predict where new lines will occur.

Is it possible to detect the textbox's vertical-scroll bar value/min/max, so that I can know how many hidden lines there are? (and increase the textbox size until there to eliminate scrolling)

I have the textbox with:

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
```

Comment: FYI: To count the lines better use `TextBox1.Lines.Count`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to use [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb.aspx) to calculate the size of the text and then resize your control accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, you could set the width of columns and rows in a Grid layout panel to "Auto" and have it determine the size you need, alternatively if you're using WinForms perhaps something like this would help?

[VB.NET: Finding the size of text to be drawn, before it is drawn to a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898841/vb-net-finding-the-size-of-text-to-be-drawn-before-it-is-drawn-to-a-control)